# How to feature-select scikit transformers within FeatureUnion

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection, grid-search

I have a machine-learning classification task that trains from the concatenation of various fixed-length vector representations. How can I perform auto feature selection or grid search or any other established technique in scikit-learn to find the best combination of transformers for my data?

Take this text classification flow as an example:

```py
model = Pipeline([
   ('vectorizer', FeatureUnion(transformer_list=[
      ('word-freq', TfidfVectorizer()),        # vocab-size dimensional
      ('doc2vec', MyDoc2VecVectorizer()),      # 32 dimensional (custom transformer)
      ('doc-length', MyDocLengthVectorizer()), # 1 dimensional (custom transformer)
      ('sentiment', MySentimentVectorizer()),  # 3 dimensional (custom transformer)
      ...                                      # possibly many other transformers
   ])),
   ('classifier', SVC())
])
```

I suspect this may fall under the requested `dynamic-pipeline` functionality of [scikit slep002](https://scikit-learn-enhancement-proposals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/slep002/proposal.html). If so how to handle in the interim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not quite able to "*choose the best (all or nothing) transformer subset of features*", we can use scikit's `feature selection` or `dimensionality reduction` modules to "*choose/simplify the best feature subset across ALL transformers*" as an extra step before classification:

```py
model = Pipeline([
   ('vectorizer', FeatureUnion(transformer_list=[...])),
   ('feature_selector', GenericUnivariateSelect(
      mode='percentile',
      param=0.20,          # hyper-tunable parameter
   )),
   ('classifier', SVC())
])
```

In a feature discovery context (ie: find the optimal expressive signals), this technique is more powerful over cherry-picking transformers. However, in an architecture discovery context (ie: find the optimal pipeline layout & use of transformers) this problem seems to remain open..